# SqlServer Select Where In

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm thrown for a loop on this one, and wondering if I don't fully understand the select where in usage or if I've just made a boo boo in this code:

```
DECLARE @driver TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @driver select eventid from event where event_code_name IS NULL
select eventid from event where eventid in (select eventid from @driver)
```

There are 3137 records total in the event table.  There are 458 records who's event_code_name field is null.  In the select above I'm expecting 458, but I'm getting all event records back instead.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `(select eventid from @driver)` should be `(select id from @driver)`

Comment: That is why I always include the table like: (select d.id from @driver as d)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using 2 tables, one virtual and one physical, the solution is to use the `INNER JOIN` clause:

```
DECLARE @driver TABLE (ID INT)
INSERT INTO @driver SELECT eventid FROM event WHERE event_code_name IS NULL
SELECT eventid FROM event INNER JOIN @driver ON id = event.eventid
```

This way you only get the IDs that are present in both the event table and the @driver table.

`INNER JOIN` is also much more efficent than using an `IN (SELECT ...)`

Without the use of the @driver table you can just obtain the same result using the SELECT query you used in the INSERT statement:

```
SELECT eventid FROM event WHERE event_code_name IS NULL
```

Comment: This would have worked too, but the original mystery/problem has been solved!

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a DISTINCT?

select DISTINCT  eventid from event where eventid in (select eventid from @driver)

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth performing an `ISNULL` on all columns that may contain a null value and filtering out the default value of the `ISNULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Using IN operator can be less efficient sometimes, Specially if your column in sub query is Nullable IN operator can show some really unexpected results.

I would suggest using EXSITS, something like this...

```
select eventid 
from [event] 
where EXISTS (select 1 
              from @driver
              WHERE id = [event].eventid)
```

For your this specific query you dont really need a table variable. you can simple do a select againt your table, something like this...

```
SELECT eventid 
FROM [event]
WHERE event_code_name IS NULL
```

Comment: I need the driver table since later, after this initial selection of NULL event_code_name(s) I will run it through several additional steps that add a value to the field.  This value I have to scrub, so several additional updates happen and so I need the driver table to do this (NULL is no longer a valid selection criteria after my first  update).